# How to create a numeric vector which gives a uniform grid for all dimensions of a matrix X?

Tags: arrays, matlab, grid, range, edges

I'm applying the function histcnd to a matrix of size 744x2. This function calculates frequencies of values within certain edges. I want to set the edges to, for example, groups of 5 values, but I can't seem to be able to do it.

The syntax of the function is histcnd(X,edges), where edges must have the same length to the number of columns of X. How do I define 'edges' as a 2-column vector, so that it will group values of each column every 5 values?

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like this:

```
X = randn(744,2);
[a,b] = size(X);
edges = num2cell([linspace(min(X(1,:)),max(X(1,:)),a/5); linspace(min(X(2,:)), max(X(2,:)),a/5)],2);

# not sure if it's the same histcnd, the one I found wants edges to be a cell array
H = histcnd(X, edges);
```

You can probably pick the min/max values for each axis in a more intelligent way if you know something about your data.